# Использование Case в Parameters

Tags: sql-server, case

Как можно использовать `case when .. then` в `@Parameters`?
При использовании нижнего примера фильтровать не получается.

Например:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  case when [APPROVAL_STATUS]  = 'approved' then 'Согласовано'  
  when [APPROVAL_STATUS]  = 'denied' then 'Отказано'    
  when [APPROVAL_STATUS]  = 'pending'  then 'В ожидании'    
  when isnull([APPROVAL_STATUS], ' ') = '' then 'Не указано'    
  ELSE [APPROVAL_STATUS] end as [APPROVAL_STATUS]
FROM [dbo].[SUMMARY]
```

И возможно ли это?

Answer (score 0):

Вот рабочий пример, попробуйте по аналогии:

```
SELECT
CASE shortname
    WHEN "обл" THEN  concat( formalname , " область")
    WHEN "край" THEN  concat( formalname , " край")
    WHEN "Респ" THEN  concat( "Республика " ,formalname )
    WHEN "АО" THEN  concat( formalname , " АО")
    WHEN "Аобл" THEN  concat( formalname , " АО")
    WHEN "Чувашия" THEN  concat( formalname)
    WHEN "г" THEN  concat( "г. ",formalname)
    ELSE formalname
END
 as `label` ,
CASE shortname
    WHEN "г" THEN 1
    else 0
    END
    as   `federalCity`,
 aoguid as `value`, regioncode
 FROM d_fias_addrobj where actstatus=1 and aolevel=1 ORDER BY formalname ASC
```

Comment: @Parameter подошел,а в запросе теперь вместо [APPROVAL_STATUS] использовать label? Не совсем понятно..

Comment: ' as `label`  ' в данном случае псевдоним поля, можете указать любое как вам нужно.